# R returning error in Rgtk2 program stating 'externalptr' is not subsettable

Tags: r, user-interface, gtk

I am beginning to write an R GUI with RGtk2 and am receiving an error with the third line of my code

```
library(RGtk2)
window <- gtkWindow()
window["title"] <- "Testing"
```

The error is 'externalptr' is not subsettable

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.12.2 (2011-02-25)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RGtk2_2.20.19

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.12.2
```

Comment: Without the error message I think it will be hard to help you !

Comment: @agstudy I just added the error into the main body

Comment: Code runs fine for me.  Can you post the output of `sessionInfo()` after you run that code?

Comment: @Dason just changed my main post to include the sessionInfo()

Comment: Can you update your version of R and also update to the newest version of RGtk2?  You're a few version behind the latest releases on both R and RGtk2

Comment: If I update, will my R code be compatible with the new version?

Comment: Yes, it will, but remember to do `update.packages(ask=FALSE)` after updating R-base